# Change the first two columns of a HTML5 form using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML5 form and would like to change the colour of its 2 first columns.

How can I do this using CSS3?

Here is the table in my html code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td >
            {{ Form::checkbox('cb_cv_tel1', '1', true) }}
        </td>
        <td >
            {{ Form::checkbox('cb_internet_tel1', '1', true) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::label('telephone1', 'Téléphone 1') }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::text('telephone1', 'Test Téléphone 1', array('id' => 'telephone1')) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Form::select('tel_type1', array(
                'mobile'    => 'mobile',
                'domicile'  => 'domicile',
                'fax'       => 'fax',
                'direct'    => 'direct',
                'autre'     => 'autre'
                ), 'mobile') }}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Google ` table columns' and `<colspan>`. As much as I hate to link W3Schools...http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(2){
background:red;
}
```

Comment: you can even write it shorter: nth-of-type(-n+2)

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities: you can give first 2 columns the class or you can play with child element in CSS3.

I would suggest:

```
    <td class="first">
        ...
    </td>
    <td class="second">
        ...
    </td>
    <td >
        ...
    </td>
    ...
```

CSS3:

```
    .first{
        background:green;
    }
    .second{
        background:yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `<thead>` you may easily  add a pseudo-element to the first row cells to draw , according to column's width a background, , else select them with `table tr:first-of-type td /* and /or th */` if you run out of `<thead>`

Setting an overflow on table and a hudge pseudo-element under the first cells of your table can allow you to draw each column with different backgrounds, even if column resizes.
this col background element has a virtual height set to 0; to be kept in the flow.:
example :http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dDwmf or http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xqALu

```
table {overflow:hidden;width:80%;margin:auto;}
th {background:yellow;}
th:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:3000px;/* hudge size */
  margin-bottom:-3000px; /* height virtually resize to zero to avoid extra overflow on html/body */
  background:yellow url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800/nature/3) center;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(200,200,20,0.5); /* will produce a color layer over background-image on max 400pixels width for example */
}
th:nth-child(even) {
  background:turquoise ;
}
th:nth-child(even):after {
  background:turquoise url(http://lorempixel.com/600/800/nature/2) center;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(0,200,200,0.5);
}
```

this method allows you to still give backgrounds to th/td of tables, **think it like a `<col/>` background possibilities that CSS doesn't really simply give us**.
To select like the two first col , use this selector : `nth-of-type(-n+2)`
a fork sibbling the first two cols http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JHKak